# R package installation error in Ubuntu

Tags: r

I got the error while installing the rgl,maps packages using Rstudio version 3.0.2, in ubuntu 14.04

```
install.packages("rgl")
install.packages("maps")
```

error:

```
Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. check the system requirement on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html

Comment: I get this message if I typed `installed.packages("rgl")`. Are you sure you didn't autocomplete to the wrong function or something?

Comment: i got another error,while installed rgl package....!!!!!                                                                                                             configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/home/priya/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Here the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/34480079/4606005