# I am unable to download the reshape2 package in R

Tags: r, package, installation, reshape2

I am getting this response when trying to install the R package:

```
>installed.packages("reshape2")
     Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances
     License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum
     NeedsCompilation Built
```

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

Comment: Is it a typo or did you try `install.packages('reshape2')`? (Not installed.packages)

Answer (score 34):

The function you have called **is not used to download packages**.

[`installed.packages`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/installed.packages.html) returns information about packages available to R. The first argument defines places where the function will be looking for packages. Unless there is `reshape2` directory in your current working directory that happens to contain some valid packages, the function will return nothing.

If you want to **download and install** package, use [`install.packages`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html):

```
install.packages("reshape2")
```

If you want to **download** package (but not install it), use [`download.packages`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.packages.html).

Comment: hmm, it seems auto-complete in R seems to troll beginners like me :) I really didn't notice (install vs installed) until I saw this post.